# JSON.parse: unexpected character when receiving assoc array from PHP json_encode

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, post

**UPDATE**

So the JQuery.post() function receives valid JSON. I know the attribute "json" in the function call should already be enough to get the original array and .parseJSON() is not necessary. I guess that's why I get the syntax error when using this function.

But somehow **I still can't access the array without the .parseJSON()**. In fact, when I use typeof(data) it's still a string. I can write it to the console and it's still valid JSON.

How do I use my array (originally associated PHP array encoded once via json_encode()) as normal associated array in JavaScript?

**ORIGINAL POST**

I've been getting this syntax error for days and it's driving me crazy. I read a lot of posts and I know it must be a super simple thing I'm missing. Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
var institute = $.post("../libraries/load_content.php",
    {
        funct:   "getInstituteAddress",
        ins_name: "Institut für Informatik",
        ins_city: "Kiel"
    }, "json");
    institute.done(function(data) {
        alert(data);
        var ins_data = $.parseJSON(data); // <-- throws syntax error
        $("#street").empty().val(ins_data['ins_street']);
        $("#number").empty().val(ins_data['ins_number']);
        $("#postalcode").empty().val(ins_data['ins_postal_code']);
    }, "json");
    institute.fail(function(data) {
        console.log("Retrieving institute data failed. Returned:"+data);
    });
```

The JQuery.post() function calls a php script, which fetches the required data from the DB and returns an associative array with json_encode().

This works fine till this point.

```
{"ins_name": "Institut für Informatik",
 "ins_street": "HRSl",
 "ins_number": "42",
 "ins_postal_code": "24118",
 "ins_city": "Kiel"}
```

Above I alert the returned String and the [JSONLint validator](http://jsonlint.com/) tells me it's valid JSON.

So I copied the String directly into the parseJSON() call. Worked fine. Why not with the variable?

Here's what I tried:

- I often read about missing single/double quotes. No luck here. Added them in multiple variations acound the String.
- I also often read that the parseJSON function is not required in such environment. So I dropped the function call. The syntax error of course disappears, but the I can't read the JSON as normal array so the fields are just emptied.
- I tried replacing the .post() function by .ajax(), adding the missing arguments... with the same effect.
- I changed the dataType attributes to html or text. Again no luck.

Comment: You've added `, 'json');` to your `$.post` call.  This tells jQuery to parse the JSON for you.  Your `data` parameter is *already* an object, no need to use `$.parseJSON`.

Comment: Try to use `console.log(data)` (`alert` is not a very good debugging tool).

Comment: That's what I tried before. But how do I then use the array? The fields keep being emptied.

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Comment: `$("#street").empty()` removes all children of the element.  I don't think this is what you want.

Comment: What do you see if you `console.log(data)`?

Comment: I get the same as when printing it with alert.
[
    19: 17: 41.861
]
"{
    "ins_name": "InstitutfürInformatik",
    "ins_street": "HRSl",
    "ins_number": "42",
    "ins_postal_code": "24118",
    "ins_city": "Kiel"
}"

Comment: What does `console.log(typeof data);` show?

Comment: It's a String. And it's in JSON. I still don't get it. How can I use it as assoc array?

Comment: @LarsN: And `$.parseJSON(data)` throws an error with that string?  That's weird.

Comment: It does with _data_. When I copy the String and insert it directly, it works fine.

Comment: Try this for me: `$.post("../libraries/load_content.php", {funct: "getInstituteAddress", ins_name: "Institut für Informatik", ins_city: "Kiel"}, function(data){ console.log(data); console.log(typeof data); }, 'json');`  Does this line work?  I'm really lost here as to why you're seeing this issue.

Comment: Also, I'm surprised there's a `ü` in the JSON.  I thought PHP encoded that as `"\u00fc"`.  How are you creating that JSON?

Comment: Well the console just says, that the POST worked fine, nothing more.
I create JSON via PHP function json_encode($array).

Comment: There's something I'm missing here.  I can't figure out why you're having trouble.  Sorry :(

Comment: I don't see why, but your code returns an object including HTTP status code and other things. Mine just returns the JSON string.
Thanks for helping me anyway! :)

Comment: @LarsN: Yours should return the same as mine.

Comment: Your code also fails. In the Web Console I can see the JSON String in the returned object, but it's a fail (enters .fail(), but not .done())

Comment: When I remove the function with the 2 console.log statements, the POST is successful again. But then it's like my code. The same JSON String.

Comment: When building the JSON, you only ever call `json_encode` once, right?

Comment: I had a similar issue involving php json_encode() and JQuery $getJSON(). The source of the problem was a naive error in one of my early php ajax files which included ... <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W2C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">